# Can't create multiple datepicker using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a problem. I have a dynamic form that can generate a rows of textfields and these textfields are should be datepicker. These textfields have same classes but only the first one has a datepicker. The rest can't generate a datepicker. But when I checked their classes they have the class of datepicker.

Here's my simple code:

```
function addNewRowCheck() {

        check_html = '<tbody id="check-row' + check_row + '">';
            check_html += '<tr style="background-color: #FDCACB">';
                check_html += '<td class="txt-center"><input type="hidden" name="check[' + check_row + '][order_no]" value="' + check_row + '" /></td>';
                check_html += '<td>';
                    check_html += '<select>';
                        check_html += $select_account_type;
                    check_html += '</select>';
                check_html +- '</td>';
                check_html += '<td><input type="text" class="txt-center chkdate" name="check[' + check_row + '][curr]" /></td>';
                check_html += '<td><input type="text" class="txt-right" name="check[' + check_row + '][rate]" /></td>';
                check_html += '<td><input type="text" class="txt-right" name="check[' + check_row + '][amount]" /></td>';
                check_html += '<td><input type="text" class="txt-right" name="check[' + check_row + '][check_number]" /></td>';
                check_html += '<td><input type="text" class="txt-right chkdate" name="check[' + check_row + '][check_date]" /></td>';
                check_html += '<td><input type="text" class="txt-right" name="check[' + check_row + '][bank_name]" /></td>';
                check_html += '<td class="center"><img id="remove_btn" src="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" onclick="$(\'#check-row' + check_row + '\').remove()" style="display: inline;" /></td>';
            check_html += '<tr>';
        check_html += '</tbody>';

        $('#check-content tfoot').before(check_html);

        check_row++;

}
```

....

```
$('.chkdate').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

Comment: After adding a new row, you have to set it manually to let it be a datepicker. Your code only initializes the already there to be datepicker, not the dynamically added ones.

Comment: there is no event delegation kind of way to handle plugin initialization... you need to do it after the new element is created... so `var $new = $(check_html).insertBefore('#check-content tfoot');
$new.find('.chkdate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** you start jquery click  function***

```
$("input[type=text]").click(function() {

    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```